# Check if input is float or not in C?

Tags: c

I am trying to create a code which checks if user input is float or not. This is what I have:

```
while (ceil(var1) == var1 || ceil(var2) == var2) {
            printf("Not float \n");
            printf("enter float: ");
            scanf("%f,%f", var1, var2);

            var1 = *num1;
            var2 = *num2;
    }
```

This works a little, but if I enter something like: `2,3` it will not accept this as a float.

Comment: Your code is not complete.  What are `var1` and `var2` defined as?  And what are `num1` and `num2`?

Comment: @AndrewHenle var1 and var2 are both defined as float and var1 and var2 as well

Comment: What are `num1` and `num2`?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: above code should check if input is float number or not.

Comment: Post the full code please.

Comment: *var1 and var2 are both defined as float and var1 and var2 as well*  `scanf()` requires that you pass the address of a variable, as C passes by value, thus `scanf()` needs the address of your variable in order to change its value.

Comment: Given that `var1` and `var2` have type `float` all values are float.  Floating point is not a quality of a number, it is a method of representing *real* numbers in a computer.  What the user enters is a *string*, and the %f format specifier interprets that string as a float.  If the conversion is sucessful (whucg you don't check), you only have a float.  What it appears you are asking is how to determine whether a `float` has a fractional part.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33992605/how-to-check-if-a-string-from-a-text-file-is-an-int-or-float-or-nonestring/

Comment: User input is text. You can choose to interpret that as just text, or integers, or floats, if you choose. Of course it is possible to detect if the user entered something validly represents a number--but how you choose to store that number is up to you.

Comment: On review, the posted duplicate is not a good fit.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33992605/how-to-check-if-a-string-from-a-text-file-is-an-int-or-float-or-nonestring?lq=1 is better.  Voting to re-open.  Yet there are still many unclear things about this post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that what you are trying to determine is whether a floating point variable has a fractional part or not (or whether the `float` input can be represented exactly as an integer perhaps).  That is not the same as whether the

> input is float or not

which really makes no sense, a `float` variable is always `float`.

Comparing floating point values for equality is always going to be problematic.  You generally have to test the difference between the two values is less than some arbitrarily small but representable and acceptable error limit.  For example:

fabs(ceil(var1) - var1) < FLT_EPSILON

You might try using `modf()`, but it may have the same issue.
    double intpart ;
    double fractpart = modf( var1, &intpart ) ; 
    if( fabs( fractpart ) < FLT_EPSILON )
    {
        // no fractional part
    }

Note that the C math library is defined for `double` rather then `float`.  In many cases the implicit conversions are safe, but not for passing the pointer prameter for `modf()`.